# How to attach multiple worker for a queue in rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using exchange based pattern in Rabbit MQ.

Producer --> Exchange --> Queues --> Consumer1

How do I run multiple consumer (C1, C2, C3 so on....) for load balancing purpose and scalability of the consumers.

Is it ok run ./worker.js twice thrice based on uses?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be ok to run your workers multiple times as that would run multiple instances of your worker listening to your queue to achieve what you want. Please refer this [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html) from RabbitMQ for more info. Specifically see section **Round-robin dispatching**

To quote a few details:

> One of the advantages of using a Task Queue is the ability to easily parallelise work. If we are building up a backlog of work, we can just add more workers and that way, scale easily.
>   You need three consoles open. Two will run the worker.js script. These consoles will be our two consumers - C1 and C2.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on @AJS answer. You may want to make use of a 'Process Monitor/Manager' like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage your long-running program C1 and most importantly to run multiple of them (C1, C2, C3 so on....). Just install supervisor in your environment (local, VPS, Docker etc), then add a configuration file like the example below to make it run, monitor and restart multiple worker.js processes as needed,

So, create a supervisor configuration file for your program, eg. my_awesome_worker.conf and place it /etc/supervisor/conf.d directory.

```
[program:wise_worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=node /my_app_location/worker.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=4
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp.out.log
user=myuser
```

To update the changes, run

```
 $sudo supervisorctl reread
 $sudo supervisorctl update
```

Note the process_name and numprocs section is responsible for running 4 worker.js processes (keep numprocs equal to or less than your number of CPUs). The numprocs in combination with process_name expression of %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d, will create four processes, namely wise_worker_00, wise_worker_01, wise_worker_02 and wise_worker_03.

Verify that they are all running using

```
$sudo systemctl status supervisor
```

or

```
$sudo service supervisor status
```